# 'Launch Error' in Eclipse IDE when running program as Java Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, automation, appium

I have been following tutorials on YouTube to try and get Appium automation to work on an Android device. I have all my capabilities and code written to open the calculator app, however, when I try to run my program as a Java Application, I get this error message:
[Launch Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL61q.png)

I find that when I click the regular run button then my program works with no problems. However, when I try to run it as a Java Application is when I get this error. I've looked online for anyone who has had this issue, but I could not find a solution. I tried to look into my run configurations but I am still having no luck.

.log file:

```
    !SESSION 2021-11-24 10:04:58.905 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=17.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product C:\Users\Mehdi.AlSaffar\OneDrive - Gentex Corporation\Desktop\Appium Projects\eclipse\appiumtests\src\test\java\appiumtests\CalculatorTest.java
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product C:\Users\Mehdi.AlSaffar\OneDrive - Gentex Corporation\Desktop\Appium Projects\eclipse\appiumtests\src\test\java\appiumtests\CalculatorTest.java

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2021-11-24 10:05:15.353
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Mehdi.AlSaffar'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 4 150 2021-11-24 10:06:07.959
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.findTypes(JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.searchAndLaunch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.launch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runInternal(LaunchShortcutAction.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3922)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3524)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$26(ProgressManager.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:987)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.findTypes(JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.java:165)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "H" under radix 16
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.isJRE12Plus(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.initialize(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.<init>(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathLocation.forJrtSystem(ClasspathLocation.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.mapToClassPathLocation(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.<init>(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.IndexBasedJavaSearchEnvironment.create(IndexBasedJavaSearchEnvironment.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.initialize(MatchLocator.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine$1.run(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 4 0 2021-11-24 10:06:07.961
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$26(ProgressManager.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.run(ProgressManager.java:987)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.findTypes(JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.searchAndLaunch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaLaunchShortcut.launch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runInternal(LaunchShortcutAction.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3922)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3524)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "H" under radix 16
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.isJRE12Plus(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.initialize(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.<init>(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathLocation.forJrtSystem(ClasspathLocation.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.mapToClassPathLocation(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.<init>(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.IndexBasedJavaSearchEnvironment.create(IndexBasedJavaSearchEnvironment.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.initialize(MatchLocator.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine$1.run(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Root exception:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "H" under radix 16
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.isJRE12Plus(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.initialize(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.<init>(ClasspathJrtWithReleaseOption.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.ClasspathLocation.forJrtSystem(ClasspathLocation.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.mapToClassPathLocation(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.computeClasspathLocations(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.JavaSearchNameEnvironment.<init>(JavaSearchNameEnvironment.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.IndexBasedJavaSearchEnvironment.create(IndexBasedJavaSearchEnvironment.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.initialize(MatchLocator.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1373)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine.searchMainMethods(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.MainMethodSearchEngine$1.run(MainMethodSearchEngine.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: @greg-449 I found this file but it is very long. I am not sure where to look or which part would be helpful to you. Do you know what I should look for in this file?

Comment: Show us th first part starting with the `!SESSION`  line

Comment: @greg-449 I have added the beginning of this file to my question. Sorry, I am new to this completely and am trying to learn on my own. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't show the error, try deleting the .log and just doing that one operation.

Comment: @greg-449 I have done so and I updated the post with the entire .log file that was generated.

Comment: Probably [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564922) which was fixed in Eclipse 4.17 (you have 4.15). Update to the latest Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21) (or 2021-12 in a week or so!)

Comment: @greg-449 I will update my eclipse and see. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: updating my eclipse fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of eclipse fixed this issue for me.